# Not able to see logs on stackdriver while using logging appender in java

Tags: java, logging, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver

My application is in dropwizard, recently I have uploaded it on gcp. For logging we need to use stackdriver. I am not gcp expert just followed https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/java . I used logging appender way to show logs on stackdriver.

As much I understood to implement stackdriver logging using logging appender we need to do basic 2 things :

1. add appender for cloud in logback.xml
2. add dependancy 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-logging-logback:0.77.0-alpha' in
   build.gradle.

I am not able to see logs on stackdriver whenever I am selecting the instance where application is deployed.

Answer (score 0):

For dropwizard it's slightly more complicated as it's *very* opinionated. Here are the steps you need to use stackdriver logging with cloud logging. Note: I used version `0.77.0-alpha` of the `com.google.cloud:google-cloud-logging-logback` library.

1. Create a class that implements `AppenderFactory<ILoggingEvent>` that has a `JsonTypeName` annotation:

```
@JsonTypeName("stackdriver")
public class StackdriverLoggingAppenderFactory implements AppenderFactory<ILoggingEvent> {

    @Override
    public Appender<ILoggingEvent> build(LoggerContext context, String applicationName,
                                         LayoutFactory<ILoggingEvent> layoutFactory,
                                         LevelFilterFactory<ILoggingEvent> levelFilterFactory,
                                         AsyncAppenderFactory<ILoggingEvent> asyncAppenderFactory) {
        final LoggingAppender appender = new LoggingAppender();
        appender.setName("stackdriver");
        appender.setContext(context);
        appender.start();
        return appender;
    }
}
```

2. Add the value of the annotation to the dropwizard configuration (yaml) file's logging section:

```
logging:
  level: INFO
  appenders:
  - type: stackdriver
```

3. Add a file called `io.dropwizard.logging.AppenderFactory` to `src/main/resources/META-INF.services`. The file should contain the fully-qualified package and class name creted in Step 1, e.g.,

```
com.acme.gcp.logging.StackdriverLoggingAppenderFactory
```

4. Finally, add an environment variable with the key `GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT` and value of the project id where the instance is run.

I tested this by running an application locally on my laptop and I could see the log entries in the Google Cloud Console under `Stackdriver Logging`.